# SQL Server Stored Procedure Default Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, default-value

I want to create a SQL Server (2008 for now) stored procedure where the parameters if not submitted are defined. Google and MS.com suggest the following but it does not work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Contracts].test2
    @first int = 6, -- default value of 6
    @second int,    
    @third int      
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @first, @second, @third;
END
```

Results:  0  |  value entered | value entered

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the code you used to call this? Are you calling it using T-SQL or something else like C#? If you use named parameters and exclude the optional parameter this should work fine.

Comment: how do you call the procedure?

Comment: Works fine in SQL Fiddle (minus the semicolons):  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb85f/1.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the feedback, I WAS using NaviCat 11 to create/test . . . when I open the same (NaviCat created) SP in SSMS it opens as:

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the stored procedure like this, it will work.

```
exec test2 @second=1, @third=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, thanks for the feedback, I WAS using NaviCat 11 to create/test . . . when I open the same (NaviCat created) SP in SSMS it opens as:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [Contracts].[test2]
    @first int = 6, -- NULL default value
    @second int,    -- Default value of 2
    @third int      -- Default value of 3
AS

BEGIN

    SELECT @first, @second, @third;

END
```

and then runs "correctly" (whereas in NaviCat it for some reason returns zero for @first whenever no param value was entered).